# how to check parent in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I bind a click event over the `document`. I have a div with id `parent`. Now whenever the click event occur over the `document` than i am trying to check the target element is the child of `div ( id = parent )` or not.

```
   <div id="parent">
    <div id="c1">
     <div id="gc1">
     </div>
     <div id="gc2">
     </div>
     ...
    </div>
    ...
   </div>
```

For this purpose i wrote the following jquery code :

```
$(document).click( function(e) {
     if($(e.target).parents("#parent").length > 0)  //this condition is not 
                                                      working as expected
     { }
});
```

What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: it is working ... see http://jsfiddle.net/2EcQb/

Comment: Chad is right, but I'm assuming you will (in practise) be using a class. What is it that is going wrong? Are there any errors thrown in your browser's debugging tool?

Comment: @Chad the point of calling `.parents()` is not to find that specific element, but to check if that specific element is an _ancestor_.

Comment: @Alnitak whoopsie! [DELETED!](http://www.hrwiki.org/w/images/c/cc/deleted.PNG)

Answer (score 1):

If the code you posted is verbatim, you forgot to declare `e` as a parameter to the callback function.

Apart from that, your code looks like it should work fine.  However, for efficiency you could use `.closest()` rather than `.parents()` since that'll only return 0 or 1 elements, and not the entire chain of elements.

Comment: sorry for that but that was the typo and i fixed that

Answer (score 1):

You could use [jQuery.contains()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/)

```
if( $.contains( document.getElementById('parent'), e.target) ) {

}
```

This will check if the target is *contained* within the *parent* container.

From the docs:

> Note: The first argument must be a DOM element, not a jQuery object or plain JavaScript object.

*This is the reason for the getElementById..*

Comment: Why must it be a DOM element? The function works perfect using document...just curious

Comment: correction: I believe the jQuery docs meant DOM object not just DOM elements. Basically just not a jQuery object or JavaScript native object.

Comment: Ok, that makes a little more sense

Answer (score 0):

EDIT Use closest...  Working [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/T8cPk/)

First...this may not completely answer your question but you need the (e) in the click function.

```
$(document).click( function(e) {
 if($(e.target).closest("#parent").length > 0) 
 { }
});
```

Comment: `.parent()` will only check the closest ancestor, not the whole tree